# Why is my TP-LINK TL-WDN4800 wireless network adapter not detected in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, wireless-adapter

I recently installed the [TP-LINK TL-WDN4800](http://www.tp-link.com/lk/products/details/cat-11_TL-WDN4800.html) wireless adapter into a PCI-E slot in my computer which is running Windows 8.1. When I use the disk and run the setup on it, I get the following popup that says the wireless network adapter is not detected:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: do you see a network adapter with a yellow icon in device manager? If yes, install the driver manually with by selecting the inf file: http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/9695-driver-install-device-manager-windows-8-a.html

Comment: Is the device detected in device manager?

Answer (score 0):

Go to manage in windows and make sure windows is detecting your hardware .It must be listed under Ports or network adapters or anywhere you may remove tp link to see if list is being updated or computer actually reads your device .if not then sadly I don't think so your tp link is working or your ports are damaged somehow

If you see your device then
1)remove your drive physically and uninstall tp-link softwares
2) install tp-link without inserting drive 
3) it will say that it couldn't find device and retry after inserting the drive
4) now insert your drive and click on retry
Hope it will fix it

I had same problem so following above steps solved it like charm and by the way make sure your software version matches with your device 
Thanks!
Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

Old-school answers, in no particular order:

- Try it in a different slot (seriously; these quirks still exist), and if you have other cards in other slots, try changing their order -- particularly if one of them is a video card (video cards always were finicky buggers).
- Check for interrupt conflicts (in case plug and play failed to read everything in correctly):

Control Panel > Device manager > Network adapters > double-click your adapter.

The IRQ is on the "Resources" tab; it should read "No conflicts" in the field at the bottom.